# VMWare player on debian host fails to update

Tags: debian, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've had VMWare Workstation Player 15 (and then recently 16) runnning on my Debian 11 for about 2.5 years now, and updating either Player or Tools has never worked. The error thrown is a string encoding issue and I thought to myself "no need to ask, it'll probably get fixed soon". Since there's still nothing on Google, I think it's time. Maybe it's straightforward.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd3S8.png

VMWare Player comes as a .bundle and gets as close to a one click installer as it can. That means that my interaction with the updater is just as inexistent. All I get is the error. I can, however, copy any /tmp/ files at this point in time and restart the installer if that's a possibility.

Looking through the source, it appears as though it's parsing some paths. Stupidly running site.py with the bundled python will print some stuff, none of which have ascii issues.

It would help if someone

- knows what's happening and can provide a solution or workaround
- knows about the paths that are being scanned and can provide a pointer where to look for ascii-issues
- knows how to restart the installer, potentially allowing to monkeypatch the ascii codec file
- has some other input towards not having to manually download and reinstall all of the upates.

Edit: I found a link to the VMWare repository (http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/ws/16.1.2/17966106/linux/packages/), where I downloaded the .tar for my Windows VM. Since the vmware-installer is an installed binary, vmware-installer --install-component xxx.component.tar should work. However, I'm getting the same ascii issue as before. Except now I can run it in a debugger.

Comment: Have you got an up to date Kernel on this machine? That is about all I see stopping things.

Comment: Also follow VMware support articles for updating kernel headers for Linux

Comment: Yeah, always up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So years after first encountering the issue, I've finally solved it. Spoiler: it's not the encoding.

VMWare builds its own PYTHONPATH in a little `init.sh`, which would be great, if Python actually used it - and only it. The reason the installer found stuff it didn't understand is because it looks for `.pth` files in its own installation directory, but also unadvertently in the local Python installation. I had an `easy_install.pth` lying around, which the installer was trying to load, and that caused it to fail. I deleted the `.pth` and now the installer, updater, and compiler work.

More: https://olgabotvinnik.com/blog/pythonpath-is-a-liar-site-py-and-easy-install-pth-tell/

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the VMWare Workstation Player has a different python
version embedded than your installed version.

When python starts, it tries to import the `site` module to adjust the
paths where to look for the modules.

The location of the module `site` is determined by the environment variable
`PYTHONPATH`. This variable points to `/usr/lib64/python<version>`,
and this is where it gets the module `site`.

In short, the embedded python version tries to import the `site` module
of an incompatible version, and fails.

The simplest solution (and a check of my theory), would be to remove
the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` before running the installation,
so that it does not use modules outside of the ones it has embedded:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=''
```

Comment: From the error log I'm pretty sure it's using the packaged site module, including the packaged ascii decoder.
Checking PYTHONPATH shows it's already empty string, too.

Comment: OK, so this theory is no go. The error here is with decoding a non-ASCII character. What is your LANG? Setting an explicit `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` might help.

Comment: I added it to .bashrc and `source .bashrc`'d it, but the installer still fails with the same error.

Comment: All I can say is to check that the characters in all the relevant paths are pure ascii.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figure, too. I've been trying to find out what paths those are.